# What does this symbol generally mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation

I work as a tutor, and came across the symbol $\oslash$ in the context of modular arithmetic, i.e. $5\oslash 9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, and haven't seen this before. Does anyone know of a common definition of this? I believe it to be some definition of division in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, but don't know the formal definition, and would like to for when it comes up again.

Comment: Never seen it before in that context.

Comment: Authors will often invent or introduce nonstandard notation in order to deal with binary operations in groups when they are introducing those concepts to students.  For example, the use of $\oplus$ for the addition operation in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is something that I have seen.  It is possible that this is one of those nonstandard notations.  I would seek advice from the book you are using, or from the person who is using that notation.

Comment: I have never seen it before either, but if your guess is correct that it is "division" as best as it is able to be defined in $\Bbb Z_{10}$ then more often than not that would mean multiplication of the number on the left by the multiplicative inverse of the number on the right.  The choice of this symbol would be in line with using $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ to emphasize that the addition/multiplication in $\Bbb Z_{10}$ is not exactly the same as addition/multiplication in $\Bbb Z$, but most authors I see don't bother with these either and opt to just use $+$ and $\times$ like normal.

Comment: WHERE did you see this notation?  A simple link/reference and we should be able to help you.